Formly Angular form style
I'm trying to use Formly for angular and primeng for the first time
https://v5.formly.dev/
But the example they provide looks bad:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-formly-ui-primeng?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
This is the example as they provide it:

How do I properly align that? The page doesn't explain it...
<div class="header">
    <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ngx-formly/ngx-formly/v5/logo.svg?sanitize=true" alt="" width="72" height="72">
    <h4 class="mat-h2">Angular Formly PrimeNg</h4>
  </div>
  <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <formly-form
      [form]="form"
      [model]="model"
      [fields]="fields">
    </formly-form>

    <div>
      <button pButton type="submit" label="Submit"></button>
      <button pButton type="reset" label="Reset" class="ui-button-danger"></button>
    </div>
  </form>

Component:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormlyFieldConfig } from '@ngx-formly/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
  form = new FormGroup({});
  model = {};
  fields: FormlyFieldConfig[] = [
    {
      key: 'input',
      type: 'input',
      templateOptions: {
        label: 'Input',
        placeholder: 'Input placeholder',
        required: true,
      },
    },
    {
      key: 'textarea',
      type: 'textarea',
      templateOptions: {
        label: 'Textarea',
        placeholder: 'Textarea placeholder',
        required: true,
      },
    },
    {
      key: 'checkbox',
      type: 'checkbox',
      templateOptions: {
        label: 'Checkbox',
      },
    },
    {
      key: 'select',
      type: 'select',
      templateOptions: {
        label: 'Select',
        placeholder: 'Select placeholder',
        required: true,
        options: [
          { label: 'Option 1', value: '1' },
          { label: 'Option 2', value: '2' },
          { label: 'Option 3', value: '3' },
        ],
      },
    },
    {
      key: 'radio',
      type: 'radio',
      templateOptions: {
        label: 'Radio',
        required: true,
        options: [
          { label: 'Option 1', value: '1' },
          { label: 'Option 2', value: '2' },
        ],
      },
    },
  ];

  onSubmit() {
    if (this.form.valid) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(this.model, null, 2));
    }
  }
}


See that when you use formly you choose the "theme" (you can use bootstrap, material, etc.) You should add in your styles.css the .css using import, e.g. for bootstrap, the .scss begin with @import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';

I'm using a theme: @import "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css";

I'm not prety sure if you need import futhermore primer.min.css, one theme (really I'm have no experience using formly, it's only I see googling)

If you use primeng as .css (I'm not prety sure) you should import futhermore primeng.min.css, one theme, e.g.
@import '~primeng/resources/primeng.min.css';
@import '~primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css';

In your styles.scss
